# libstdc++6 unmet dependencies installing upx-ucl

Tags: linux, debian, libstdc++, upx

I am trying to install upx-ucl on Debian, but I am getting the following notification:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
> upx-ucl : Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 13.1) but 12.2.0-14 is to be installed
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I have tried the following:

- sudo apt install upx-ucl
- sudo apt reinstall libstdc++6
- sudo apt-get -f install
- sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade
- sudo apt-get autoclean
- sudo apt-get clean
- sudo aptitude install upx-ucl
- sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
- sudo apt-get --fix-broken install

And nothing helped me. I have no clue what else to try, and I can not recall what have I installed that could cause this conflict. One thing I have installed from github is Joplin, but I am not sure that it causes this problem.

I do not know if the output od command `sudo apt show libstdc++6` will help but here it is:

```
Package: libstdc++6
Version: 12.2.0-14
Priority: optional
Section: libs
Source: gcc-12
Maintainer: Debian GCC Maintainers <debian-gcc@lists.debian.org>
Installed-Size: 2.750 kB
Depends: gcc-12-base (= 12.2.0-14), libc6 (>= 2.36), libgcc-s1 (>= 4.2)
Conflicts: scim (<< 1.4.2-1)
Breaks: gcc-4.3 (<< 4.3.6-1), gcc-4.4 (<< 4.4.6-4), gcc-4.5 (<< 4.5.3-2)
Replaces: libstdc++6-12-dbg (<< 4.9.0-3)
Homepage: http://gcc.gnu.org/
Tag: role::shared-lib
Download-Size: 614 kB
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot lory/main amd64 Packages
Description: GNU Standard C++ Library v3
 This package contains an additional runtime library for C++ programs
 built with the GNU compiler.
 .
 libstdc++-v3 is a complete rewrite from the previous libstdc++-v2, which
 was included up to g++-2.95. The first version of libstdc++-v3 appeared
 in g++-3.0.
```